# Python pendulum module returning wrong week number

Tags: python, python-3.x, week-number, pendulum

The way iam trying to get the week number

```
import pendulum
from datetime import date

dt = pendulum.parse(str(date.today())) 

week = dt.week_of_month

print(dt)

print(week)
```

**Result**

> 2023-01-19T00:00:00+00:00
>
> -48

The week number is -48 here, please help me to get the correct week number of the month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @God is One mentioned in the above answer, there's an issue with the current version and the rest of the versions in the 2.1.x series. But then when I tried to downgrade it to `2.0.5`, this worked fine and it returned the expected value.

Maybe that's the only option as of now if you're to go with this library.

Comment: I have downgraded to version 2.0.5 and it worked fine. Thank you

Comment: np.. glad it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue going with pendulum module. It is returning negative numbers for week.

Please find the attached link for reference:

https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues/587

Comment: I have downgraded to pendulum==2.0.5 and it worked fine. Thank you